# Overflow Scroll Adding Line at Bottom of Screen

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to prevent the cards I have from leaving the div they are in when I resize the screen. I added overflow scroll in order to solve this and it works the way I would like but I don't understand what is causing this weird grey outline at the bottom of page. I dont have any styling that would cause it. I'm not sure if this a browser thing but is there a way to remove it?

I know the grey bar on the right is for scroll but what is the bar on the bottom across the card for?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `overflow-y: scroll;` instead of `overflow: scroll;`. This ensures the overflow scrollbar is only applied vertically.